# Is there any shortcut for distraction-free mode?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any shortcut for distraction-free mode in IntelliJ? Or can I create one somehow? I don't want to go to view tab every time.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is none assigned by default, but you can assign one yourself.

Go to `Settings > Keymap` and type `distraction` in the filter field (or expand the `Main menu > View > Toggle Distraction Free mode` tree). Right click the item and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`.

Comment: and as a suggestion set it to (shift + f5) while it is not set to anything as default

Comment: Thank you @Eftekhari Any suggestions for a Full Screen mode shortcut? This would make my day :)

Comment: You're welcome @Angelito. You could try buttons that are easy for you and are not set to anything important. I don't remember but I think ctrl+f10 was my setting. I don't remember exactly but you could figure out something suitable.

Comment: Thanks @Eftekhari I just did ctrl+shift+f5

Comment: Thought I'd ask since I always find conflicting keybindings when I try to configure things myself lol

Comment: @Eftekhari I'm curious if you have a reason for shfit + f5, or you just chose it to set a precedent? Either way, it works! :)

Comment: @grokpot yes, it is not set to anything by default and you could set it with one hand :)

Comment: Right click is not working on my Wwindows 10, WSL Pycharm. Had to resort to keymap in settings.

Answer (score 29):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> allows you to exit/enter presentation mode, distraction mode, full screen

Comment: Might not work across all platforms. e.g. Using IntelliJ on MacOS, this doesn't work for default configurations.

Comment: Thanks! Worked in PHP Strom on a Mac :)

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, you type them one at a time; the '~' brings up the *Switch* menu, `4` is 'View Mode' and the final `2` is for Distraction Free Editing.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the default Mac shortcuts, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>.

Explanation:

Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, press <kbd>`</kbd>, release all; this brings up the `Switch...` menu. Press and release <kbd>4</kbd>; this enters the `View Mode` menu. Press and release <kbd>2</kbd>; this toggles `Enter Distraction Free Mode`/`Exit Distraction Free Mode`.

Answer (score 2):

To add a shortcut:

- go to preferences
- go to keymap and search for the function that you want
- assign the shortcut that you want(mine is <kbd>z</kbd> followed by <kbd>n</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

As I use both Distraction Free and Full Screen mode very often, I've made the following shortcuts consisting of two keystrokes:

- **Ctrl+Shift+S**  **D**  for distraction free mode
- **Ctrl+Shift+S**  **F**  for full screen mode

You can do this in Settings > KeyMap (search for "distraction").